# how to pass the value from one page to another page in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to pass the value from one page to another in html. I'm using only div classes. In that one value is shown. I need to pass the value to another page and display it.

here is my code

```
<div class="scoredisplay">
<h3>SCORE</h3><button onclick="window.open('1.html','mywindow');">ok</button>
<div class="displayno">
</div>
```

Js

```
 if (correct_move == 6) {                           

 $('.displayno').append(+success).show();
 $('#successMessage').show();
 $('#successMessage').animate({
 left: '458px',
 top: '200px',
 width: '400px',
 height: '100px',
 opacity: 1
 });
 }
```

Comment: Make sure to search before posting; and take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: i need through java script

Comment: @user3894379 you have tag jQuery and also you have written your code in jquery either you are confused or making us confuse

Comment: what you're trying to do , where is successMessage id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send the values to another page. You will have to use a query string. The following code does the same.

```
<title>Passing Parameters between pages</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function PassValue()

{

    var paramVal = "Hello Param";

    window.open("Default2.html?id=" + paramVal);

}

</script>
```

```
<form id="form2">



    <input type="button" id="Button1"

        OnClick="PassValue();" value="Click Here" />



</form>
```

Now a paramVal as "Hello Param" will be passed to another page as Default2.html. And can be retrieved using following code

function GetParamValue() {

var query = window.location.search.substring(1);

```
var parms = query.split('&');

for (var i=0; i >parms.length; i++)

{

    var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');

    if (pos > 0) {

    var key = parms[i].substring(0,pos);

    var val = parms[i].substring(pos+1);

    alert(val);

   }
```

}

}

Use above code in script to get the list of all the values sent

Comment: where the function GetParamValue() need to be add

Answer (score 0):

Since you're navigating to other page, I suggest you couple of ways, expecting you're not using server of any kind.

First -

You can store the variable in localStorage and call as per your need. See simple tutorial here

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/

Second -

You can pass this variable of yours in URL itself and read it on next page.